# How to check the Nvidia Video Memory in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: video, ram, gpu

How to check the video memory size of my Graphic card? I used (System Profiler and Benchmark) and it showing me that I have only 256MB but I have the Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti 4GB.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the nvidia additional driver and then you will see all details informations about your video cards with the nvidia tools:
[image: nvidia tool]

Usually it is installed with driver, you can launch it from menu, it is named *NVIDIA X Server Settings*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already had NVIDIA drivers but I never seen this details before.

Comment: In terminal: nvidia-smi